# Pluck id's from mongo query result

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query on mongo console

```
db.photos.find({'creation_date': {$gte: <somedate>)}}).
```

Is there a way to pluck the id's from query result just by using mongo shell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the **[`map()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)** cursor method

```
var ids = db.photos.find({'creation_date': { '$gte': <somedate>) } }, {'_id': 1})
                   .map(function (doc){ return doc._id; })
```

---

You can also use the **[`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** method as

```
var ids = db.photos.distinct('_id', {'creation_date': { '$gte': <somedate>) } })
```

---

or with the **[`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray)** cursor method on **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** as

```
var ids = db.photos.aggregate([
    { '$match': {'creation_date': { '$gte': <somedate>) } } }
    { '$group': { '_id': 0, 'ids': { '$push': '$_id' } } }
]).toArray()[0].ids
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDb provides limit fields from query results

See more about in below link

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

db.photos.find({'creation_date': {$gte: )},{"_id":1}});

returns

{
  "_id":1 
}
{
  "-id":2
}
...

Comment: If you want only ids array you can use add map(function(doc){ return doc._id})

Answer (score 2):

You can use `distinct` instead of `find`:

```
collection.distinct('_id', {'creation_date': some_date})
```